# Embedding Multiple Excel Worksheets on a form based on a query containing file paths

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, vba, ms-access

First I'll describe my goal, then I'll explain what I've done so far.

My goal is to have a database where users can fill in some fields which include fields that describe where an `excel` file is located and the range that they want to show.  There will be a form that shows all the records with the excel file embedded in it.  Basically it is sort of an overview screen where multiple excel files are embedded/linked for the content.

```
 ------------------ ---------------------------------
|    Record #1     |     Embedded/Linked Excel #1    |   
|    Record #2     |     Embedded/Linked Excel #2    |
         .                             .
         .                             .
         .                             .
```

Currently I've chosen MS Access, but I am not tied down to using VBA/Access and am willing to use something in the .NET world.  My experience of OLE objects is limited to non-"continuous" form uses so I'm not entirely aware if what I'm trying is possible or not.

In MS Access I've tried using Unbound Object Frames.  These link/embed excel files given a file path easily enough but they don't seem to have the ability to have a control source where I can bind a file path from a query.  The form needs to display more than 1 record/excel file at a time.

I've also tried using bound object frames to store the actual excel files in the table.  This is not ideal solution since the content already exists in different excel files, don't want users to have to update files in two locations - real file & OLE object in table.

Is my goal achievable in MS Access/VBA?  If not, is it achievable in C#/WPF/Winforms?  Either way if its possible how do I go about this?  Would appreciate specifics or even hints/thoughts/musings etc.

Comment: My thought is that this sounds like a *VERY* difficult database to maintain.  If someone decides to move or copy an excel file your database link is broken or out of date.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to show the ranges of the excel files *within* your `ms access` app?  I dont know how to do this in the `object frames` you talk about, but it is very achievable in c#/WPF/Winforms.

Comment: I understand the risk of broken links, but since this screen will be viewed daily, the users will be fairly disciplined or everyone will see that the file person A is working on is broken etc.  That is why I want them to be responsible for maintaining their own paths and grab it from a query instead of me just hardcoding the path into the objects

Comment: If I want to do this in C#/WPF/Winforms, any starting points your recommend?  I've never tried binding OLE objects, its always been native types of fields.

Comment: check out my answer, it should give you a good start on a wpf/winforms solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open and view `Excel` files in your `WPF/Winforms` application you need to use the [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) for the version of `Excel` than you plan to support.

[DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) has an excellent tutorial on how to get started.

In your case it would look something like:

```
public void ExcelOpenSpreadsheets(string databaseStoredExcelFileName, int worksheetNumber, string startRange, string endRange)
{
    try
    {
        Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(databaseStoredExcelFileName,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[worksheetNumber] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

        Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range(startRange, endRange);
        workBook.Close(false, thisFileName, null);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);

        //now do something with "range"
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

In order to **embed** an excel file into your `WPF/Winforms` application you will need to probably modify [this code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3582/Word-Control-for-NET) To handle `Excel` instead of `Word`.

Comment: I read through the tutorial and your code.  It explains how to get data from and excel file and how to edit one via C#. This would allow me to display/bind the data using `DataGridView` or something similar.  This isn't what I'm trying to do.  I would like to show a "preview" of the excel file the way each individual user has formatted themselves.  Is there a way to display in WPF using `interop` or is that another class/lib?

Comment: I see, you want to EMBED (i can read, i promise :) the excel file into your app, rather than display its data.  I posted a link to a good tutorial.  See my edits.